# Which layers to use for a Neural Network fit of a strange function?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, curve-fitting

I am using a neural network to find the best fit of a function that has a step aspect (blue is my real data, orange is the neural network prediction):
[image]

I am new to this and the paper I am basing myself on uses `relu` layers with a `linear` output but at the same time their data to fit looks much cleaner:
[image]

**Question:** Do you know if there would be a combination of layers that would be more adapted to a case like I have, where most of the data has this strong variations early on (left of the 1st plot) and then stabilizes ?

**Structure of my Neural Network:**
I have 5 relu layers, 1 sigmoid and 1 linear layer acting as an output. I use Adam for optimization and a custome root-mean-square error cost function. In the code, I also use a K-fold cross-validation method because the paper was using that, but I did not include it because I first need to nail the layers structure.

**Input Data:** I work with Column arrays, varying in size. That's why I use the linear layer as an output.

**Code:**

```
def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(1,)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
    model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: What does your dataset look like? This looks to me like a regression problem, where you have an input variable and an output variable, so you're trying to predict a dependent variable versus an independent variable, right?

Comment: Well the dataset is all over the place and the regression is not really supposed to work everytime. But ideally, the dataset should take the form of an earthquake's waveform: high variability for small 'X' values, and then stabilization as 'X' increases.

Comment: okei perfect, this aspect is really clear. however regarding the output variable y you want to predict? what is it and what does it represent?

Comment: X represents values of river discharge. Y represents the magnitude of temporal modes of Rotated Empirical Orthogonal Functions (REOFs) for a stack of 2D SAR images (so the stack is 3D). We assume a relationship between X and Y (see the small figure in my post, instead of taking river discharge this figure takes water level in a river).  
We are looking to forecast SAR images from forecasted river discharge (X_pred). If we have X_pred and a relationship f(X)=Y, we can do f(X_pred)=Y_pred. Then by using the spatial mode of the REOFs we can forecast the SAR images from the Y_pred

Comment: My inputs and outputs are column vectors. I then use those column vectors to reconstruct a forecasted dataset.

While in sometimes there might be a relationship between X and Y, it is an assumption. The paper I took the figure from shows that. We are expecting the forecast to be unreliable if the neural network can't find a significant relationship between X and Y. But in the case it does, then the forecast should be trustworthy. 

So I built my forecast based on the expectation that the relationship would look like a step-function, but in most cases it looks like an earthquake waveform.